# Javascript is almost working, but it then reloads page?

Tags: javascript

so I'm hiding items until someone puts in a secret word in a form. It actually works, but then it reloads the page. What am I missing? <strike>You can see it here: xxx under projects and the password is '--'.</strike>

This is the code I'm using:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function projectsvisible() 
{ 
document.getElementById("myprojects").style.display = "block"; 
}

function projectshide() 
{
document.getElementById("myprojects").style.display = "none"; 
}

function projectsshow() 
{ 
    if(document.getElementById("password").value=="danielle") 
        {
        projectsvisible(); 
        } 
    else { projectshide(); } 

} 
</script>
```

Comment: How are you calling this? Also, if the script is on the same page, that password ain't so secret :)

Comment: hi @tymeJV, thanks for the reply. I will probably be changing the password, but its not meant to be too secure, I just want to hide my projects from the general public, because of past employers etc. I just want people I send the word to to be able to see it.

I'm calling it on submit, if thats what you mean? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'll probably redo using PHP, so its not on the page, but I need to get this up today quickly, so I'm just looking for a quick solution

Comment: See one of the many solutions below, they're all pretty much the same thing. Also, re-doing in PHP is probably not the answer, PHP is server, JS is client-side. PHP will cause the refresh since the page will have to be re-written.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a form with a submit button. This creates and fires a synchronous page reloading Http Request.  You should not use a form. Just use a normal button with an on click handler and wrap them in a div instead.

Comment: This is true. I didn't think of that. I'm making things overly complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's auto-refreshing due to the button type of `submit`. This will cause a postback to the page and refresh. There's a few workarouds:

1. Add `return false;` to your inline handler or function
2. Use `e.preventDefault` where `e` is `event` passed in to the parent function
3. Change your button type of `submit` to `button`

Answer (score 0):

First, change `<form id="projectform" method="POST" action="#" class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return projectsshow(); return false">`

to

`<form id="projectform" method="POST" action="#" class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return projectsshow();">`

Then change `projectsshow()` function:

```
function projectsshow() 
{ 
    if(document.getElementById("password").value=="danielle") 
        {
        projectsvisible(); 
        } 
    else { projectshide(); }
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much!! This is exactly what I need! If you have time do you mind telling me what we did there? Why does the return false go in the projectsshow function?

Again, thanks!!

Comment: @DanielleSchechter the `onsubmit` attribute returned `projectsshow()` function's result, which was undefined (no return statement inside function), the second `return false;` was never invoked. Since `projectsshow()` returns `false`, `onsubmit` returns it too (which tells browser to not submit the form - no reload). Hope it's clear ;)

Comment: @dshesh so you can click 'accept' for this answer (as well as answers for your other questions on stackoverflow) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your button is what's reloading the page.  You can either use jQuery's event.preventDefault() on the button, or style a div to look like a button and do your onlick action on the button.

Answer (score 0):

you onsubmit handler does not return false. projectsshow() does not return false.
Therefore your form is not prevented from getting submitted and so the page refresh happens.

```
<form id="projectform" method="POST" action="#" class="form-horizontal" 
    onsubmit="return projectsshow(); return false">
```

Either fix `projectsshow()` method to return false or change onsubmit to `onsubmit="projectsshow(); return false"`